# Join 3 tables on the data model on multiple columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I have 3 tables in my Power Pivot data model that I would like to create a relationship:

Customers:

| Company | Contact | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | 10 |
| A | Michael | 20 |
| B | Jack | 30 |

Companies

| Contact | Department |
| --- | --- |
| John | Marketing |
| Michael | Engineering |
| Jack | HR |

Deals

| Department | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Engineering | Premium |
| Legal | Platinum |
| Ops | Free |

My main output table will be based on Customers, and I want to add the Department and Deal type.

Output (Pivot table)

| Company | Contact | Department | Type | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | Marketing |  | 10 |
| A | Michael | Engineering | Premium | 20 |
| B | Jack | HR |  | 30 |

In SQL the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT cu.*, cp.department, d.type
FROM Customers cu
   JOIN Company cp ON cu.contact= cp.contact
   LEFT JOIN cp.department = d.department
```

Is it possible to do this in Power Pivot?

Ideally I would like to have relationships in Power Pivot and not having to merge tables in Power Query. Otherwise I'm increasing the table size unnecessarily for a simple join.

I simplified the tables for the example, the joins are the same, but each table has many more columns.

Comment: Why not just create relationships between the tables? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-relationships-in-diagram-view-in-power-pivot-12e00cb6-cb4d-469c-97ce-caa08349ad76